# PHP - accessing a returned object array from a SOAP client request

Tags: php, arrays, list

I am very new to PHP. I am working on a project that makes a soap client request to a WSDL created from java and returns the response from the java program as List.
I want to access the string from the returned array object in php, but am not able to do so.

Please find the code that I have used below -

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://rakesh-pc:8080/WikiEdit/wikiSearchService?wsdl");
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$params = array(
"arg0" => $user,
);
$result = $client->wikiFind($params);
var_dump($result);
```

I am getting the following var_dump result for my program. Sorry, if it is not properly formatted.

```
object(stdClass)[2]                                                                     
    public 'return' => 
    array (size=41)                                                                         
    0 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism>' (length=40)    
    1 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_and_Anarchist_SkinHeads>' (length=58)    
    2 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_and_Anarchist_Skinheads>' (length=58)     
    3 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-statism>' (length=43)                   
    4 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism>' (length=49)            
    5 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-Capitalism>' (length=49)           
    6 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualist_anarchism>' (length=54)        
    7 => string '<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualist_Anarchism>' (length=54)        
    ....
```

I have tried several ways. The thing which is confusing me is that if I give count(`$result->return`) to access the object, it is giving 41, which is correct. But if I try the same thing to display the string using echo `$result->return[$i]` in a while loop, I am getting only a blank page

This may sound trivial to some of you guys here, but I have been struggling with it from yesterday. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Insert [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($result->return[$i], ENT_HTML5);
```

How to linkify:

```
// Grab the raw URL
$url = substr($result->return[$i], 1, -1);
// Echo <a> incl. the text
echo "<a href='$url'>", echo htmlspecialchars($result->return[$i], ENT_HTML5), "</a>";
```

---

**Explanation of the problem**

Please try inserting the following line at the beginning of your script:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

I suspect that the angular brackets of the strings are the "problem". The browser tries to interpret them as HTML tags, but fails and then hides them.

Sending another content-type such as plain text will prevent the browser from interpreting the output.

You can also try this method instead of the first one I provided:

```
var_dump($result->return[$i]);
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the reply. I am trying your solution now. I will let you know in a while.

Comment: I have tried both your method. The first one displays the strings in echo command itself. But all the HTML tags are also displayed along with it. I forgot to mention it you that I am using HTML as well. The second one displays the URL with the string and length attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to display the string as URL directly?

Comment: @user3025552 Sorry for the late reply. Please see my updated answer. (var_dump() is for debugging purposes, therefore it also display the string's length along with some quotes.)

Comment: Sorry about the very late reply, was outside.. It did work. It is now displaying the link as <http//wikipedai..> string. Is there any way to display the same string as a URL. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @user3025552 What do you mean by displaying as a URL? Do you want to wrap it in an `<a>` tag? Please see my updated answer if it fits your question.

Comment: Thank You @ComFreek. I did the same thing. Instead of removing the <> in PHP, I removed them in the mysql table and then used the echo "<a href>" command to display them as links.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your object to an array.  I like to use the following function:

```
function objectToArray( $object ){

    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ){
           return $object;
    }

    if( is_object( $object ) ){
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }

    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}

$myResultArray = objectToArray($result);
var_dump($myResultArray);
echo $myResultArray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result =  (array)$client->wikiFind($params);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse property result to array:

```
print_r((array)$result->return)
```

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
function objectToArray($data) {
    if (is_object($data)&& !is_array($data)) {
        $array = array();            
        $array[0] = $data;
        return $array;
    }else{
        if (empty($data)){
            return array();
        }else{
            return $data;
        }

    }        
}
```